# Azure Cosmos DB with SQL API: GetItemLinqQueryable Query clarification

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to retrieve records from Cosmos DB. I'm using the following code:

```
queryString = this._container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Family>()
                     .Where(family => family.Address.ZipCode == zipCode)
                     .ToQueryDefinition().QueryText;
```

and I thought it would produce the following query

> SELECT * FROM Family WHERE Family.address.zipcode = 90201

however it produces the following query

> SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE (root["address"]["zipcode"] = "90210")

Is it same as the above? If not, what am I missing?